# Using Divs to display table-like data

Tags: css

I want to display data like the following:

```
 Title     Subject    Summary    Date
```

So my `HTML` looks like:

```
<div class="title"></div>
<div class="subject"></div>
<div class="summary"></div>
<div class="date"></div>
```

The problem is, all the text doesn't appear on a single line. I tried adding `display="block"` but that doesn't seem to work.

What am I doing wrong here?

**Important:** In this instance I dont want to use a `table` element but stick with `div` tags.

Comment: What are you doing wrong? Displaying *tabular data* using divs. Tables are for tables, divs are for layout. Use tables instead!

Comment: +1 for using the table tag.  It isn't evil when it's used to display actual tabular data.

Comment: @The update, this site does not display tabular data.  That's why they don't use tables.  You are talking about a table.

Comment: Well displaying questions with the votes/ansnwers/quesiton summary is tabular data no?

Comment: Think about using table for data that you'd use a table in your favourite word processor. use divs when you're about to "just position something" somewhere on the page, like you'd use frames in wordprocessing (hoping are they called frames in the english UIs?)

Comment: Just as using tables for layouts is a no-no, so should using divs, or any other bunk markup for tabular data.  Think about how a screen-reader would handle your markup (badly).

Comment: I think all of you brought your thoughts on tables vs divs across pretty well. But he asked a pretty straight forward question and deserves an answer. "Use a table" is not an answer to "how does this work", so why is everyone voting these table-things up?

Comment: @sdfx Because it looks like he is trying to display variable width tabular data, which does not lend itself to any other approach.  For the columns to line up, you need control of the width of every column.  "Date" is the only field he has listed that I would trust to be a certain width/formatting.

Comment: @chris true, but maybe he takes care of the width internally, maybe not. I'm not saying that suggesting tables is the wrong thing to do, but at least explain why it is bad (like you did). the top answer (by Andy) at this point is not very helpful and a div-variant should be up there somewere too.

Comment: Anyone know of a current version of this same discussion? I still don't believe that you 'never' use tables.

Answer (score 37):

It looks like you're wanting to display a table, right?  So go ahead and use the <table> tag.

Answer (score 27):

I would use the following markup:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Subject</th>
    <th>Summary</th>
    <th>Date</th>
  </tr>
  <!-- Data rows -->
</table>
```

One other thing to keep in mind with all of these div and list based layouts, even the ones that specify fixed widths, is that if you have a bit of text that is wider than the width (say, a url), the layout will break.  The nice thing about tables for tabular data is that they actually have the notion of a column, which no other html construct has.

Even if this site has some things, like the front page, that are implemented with divs, I would argue that tabular data (such as votes, responses, title, etc) SHOULD be in a table.  People that push divs tend to do it for semantic markup.  You are pursuing the opposite of this.

Comment: I would add <thead> and <tbody> to the mix, but otherwise... this. Tables are for tabular data.

Comment: +1 for thead and tbody.  That is one area in my web development that could use improvement.

Answer (score 22):

I don't mean to sound patronizing; if I do, I've misunderstood you and I'm sorry.

Most people frown upon tables because people use them for the wrong reason.  Often, people use huge tables to position things in their website.  *This* is what divs should be used for.  Not tables!

However, if you want to display *tabular data*, such as a list of football teams, wins, losses, and ties, you should most definitely use tables.  It's almost unheard of (although not impossible) to use divs for this.

Just remember, if it's for displaying data, you can definitely use a table!

Answer (score 10):

If there's a legitimate reason to not use a table then you could give each div a width and then float it. i.e.

```
div.title {
    width: 150 px;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: ouch! any text displayed, if zoomed, could get mangled.  at least use em not px for units.

Comment: ...or specify font sizes in px as well, which effectively disables font sizing in browsers (zoom still works though).

Answer (score 5):

Is there a reason to not use tables? If you're displaying tabular data, it's best to use tables - that's what they're designed for.

To answer your question, the best way is probably to assign a fixed width to each element, and set float:left. You'll need to have either a dummy element at the end that has clear:both, or you'll have to put clear:both on the first element in each row.  This method is still not fool-proof, if the contents of one cell forces the div to be wider, it will not resize the whole column, only that cell. You maybe can avoid the resizing by using overflow:auto or overflow:hidden, but this won't work like regular tables at all.

Answer (score 4):

or indeed this, which is very literally using tables for tabular data:
https://stackoverflow.com/badges

Answer (score 4):

Just to illustrate the remarks of the previous answers urging you to use table instead of div for *tabular* data:

**[CSS Table gallery](http://icant.co.uk/csstablegallery/)** is a great way to display beautiful tables in many many different visual styles.

Answer (score 4):

Sorry, but, I'm going to tell you to use tables. Because this is tabular data.

Perhaps you could tell us why you *don't* want to use tables?

It appears to me, and I'm sure to a lot of other people, that you're confused about the "don't use tables" idea. It's not "don't use tables", it's "don't use tables to do page layout".

What you're doing here is laying out tabular data, so of course it should be in a table.

In case you're unclear about the idea "tabular data", I define it like this: bits of data whose meaning isn't clear from the data alone, it has to be determined by looking at a header.

Say you have a train or bus timetable. It will be a huge block of times. What does any particular time mean? You can't tell from looking at the time itself, but refer to the row or column headings and you'll see it's the time it departs from a certain station.

You've got strings of text. Are they the title, the summary, or the date? People will tell that from checking the column headings. So it's a table.

Comment: AMEN! I can't count how many times I've had this same response to "tables are bad tho" people.

Answer (score 2):

display:block garauntees that the elements will *not* appear on the same line. Floating for layout is abuse just like tables for layout is abuse (but for the time being, it's necessary abuse). The only way to garauntee that they all appear on the same line is to use a table tag. That, or display:inline, and use only &nbsp; (Non-Breaking Space) between your elements and words, instead of a normal space. The &nbsp; will help you prevent word wrapping.

But yea, if there's not a legitimate reason for avoiding tables, use tables for tabular data. That's what they're for.

Answer (score 2):

In the age of CSS frameworks, I really don't see a point of drifting away from table tag completely. While it is now possible to do `display: table-*` for whatever element you like, but table is still a preferred tag to format data in tabular form (not forgetting it is more semantically correct). Just pick one of the popular CSS framework to make tabular data looks nice instead of hacking the presentation of `<div>` tags to achieve whatever it is not designed to do.

---

```
display: block
```

will certainly not work, try

```
display: inline
```

or float everything to the left then position them accordingly

but if you have tabular data, then it is the best to markup in `<table>` tag

some reference: [from sitepoint](http://www.sitepoint.com/blogs/2008/09/09/rowspans-colspans-in-css-tables/)

Answer (score 2):

The CSS property float is what you're looking for, if you want to stack div's horizontally.

Here's a good tutorial on floats: http://css.maxdesign.com.au/floatutorial/

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to make sure that all your "cells" float either left or right (depending on their internal ordering), and they also need a fix width.

Also, make sure that their "row" has a fixed width which is equal to the sum of the cell widths + margin + padding.

Lastly make sure there is a fixed width on the "table" level div, which is the sum of the row width + margin + padding.

But if you want to show tabular data you really should use a table, some browsers (more common with previous generation) handle floats, padding and margin differently (remember the famous IE 6 bug which doubled the margin?).

There's been plenty of other questions on here about when to use and when not to use tables which may help explain when and where to uses divs and tables.

Answer (score 1):

Using this code :

```
<div class="title">MyTitle</div><div class="subject">MySubject</div><div class="Summary">MySummary</div>
```

You have 2 solutions (adapt css selectors to you case):

1 - Use inline blocks

```
div 
{
    display: inline;
}
```

This will result in putting the blocks on the same line but remove the control you can have over their sizes.

2 - Use float

```
div 
{
    width: 15%; /* size of each column : adapt */
    float: left; /* this make the block float at the left of the next one */
}

div.last_element /* last_element must be a class of the last div of your line */
{
   clear: right; /* prevent your the next line to jump on the previous one */
}
```

The float property is very useful for CSS positioning : http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_class_float.asp

Comment: clear:both will put the element on the next line.  You want clear:right, to keep the next floated element from being to the right of the last element.

Answer (score 1):

The reason the questions page on stack overflow can use DIVs is because the vote/answers counter is a fixed width.

Answer (score 1):

Tabular data can also be represented as nested lists - i.e. lists of lists:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        heading 1
        <ul>
            <li>row 1 data</li>
            <li>row 2 data</li>
        <ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        heading 2
        <ul>
            <li>row 1 data</li>
            <li>row 2 data</li>
        <ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Which you can layout like a table and is also semantically correct(ish).

Comment: How would something like this get laid out like a table?  Would doing so serve to break any other ul's you might have?

Answer (score 0):

For the text to appear on a single line you would have to use display="inline"

Moreover, you should really use lists to achieve this effect

```
<ul class="headers">
  <li>Title</li>
  <li>Subject</li>
  <li>Summary</li>
  <li>Date</li>
</ul>
```

The style would look like this:

.headers{padding:0; margin:0}

.headers li{display:inline; padding:0 10px} /*The padding would control the space on the sides of the text in the header*/

Comment: Why use a list to display tabular data?  That's what the table tag is for.

Comment: Also, the columns beneath would not line up properly with their headers, since each list item would have a variable width depending on its content.

Answer (score 0):

I asked a similar question a while ago [Calendar in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42169/if-you-were-programming-a-calendar-in-html-would-you-use-table-tags-or-div-tags) and everyone told me to use tables too.

If you have made an igoogle home page, just yoink their code. 
I made a system of columns and sections within the columns for a page.  Notice with google you can't have an infinite number of columns and that offends our sensibilities as object people. Here's some of my findings:

- You need to know the width of the columns

  You need to know the number of columns

  You need to know the width of the space the columns inhabit.

  You need to ensure whitespace doesn't overflow

I made a calendar with DIV tags because it is impossible to get XSL to validate without hard coding a maximum number of weeks in the month, *which is very offensive*.

---

The biggest problem is every box has to be the same height, if you want any information to be associated with a field in your table with div tags you're going to have to make sure the `whitespace:scroll` or `whitespace:hidden` is in your CSS.

Comment: What problem did you have getting XSL to validate?

Answer (score 0):

Preface: I'm a little confused by the responses so far, as doing columns using DIVs and CSS is pretty well documented, but it doesn't look like any of the responses so far covered the way it's normally done.  What you need is four separate DIVS, each one with a greater "left:" attribute.  You add your data for each column into the corresponding DIV (column).

Here's a website that should help you.  They have many examples of doing columns with CSS/DIV tags:
http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/layouts/

All you have to do is extrapolate from their 2-column examples to your 4-column needs.

Comment: Again, this is terribly anti-semantic.  Picture a screen-reader trying to read this.

Further, say row 1 has an item that is 1 line in the first column, and 2 lines in the second column.  Row 2's first column item will not line up with row 2's second column.

Answer (score 0):

You should use spans with:

```
display:inline-block
```

This will allow you to set a width for each of elements while still keeping them on the same line.
See [here](http://siteroller.net/articles/3-column-no-tables-no-floats/), specifically [this section](http://siteroller.net/articles/3-column-no-tables-no-floats/pretty-forms-1.php).

Now, to appease the downvoters - of course tabular data should be in a table.  But he very specifically does NOT WANT a table.  The above is the answer to HIS QUESTION!!!

Answer (score 0):

First `display:block` should be `display:inline-block` , Although you might have figured it out already.
Second you can also use `display:table` , `display:table-cell` , `display:table-row` and other properties.
Although these are not as good as using table.