# What is the best way to display data that is column based but yet seems non-tabular?

Tags: css

I am trying to be semantically correct here in my web pages, but not sure how to proceed:

My data looks like this or needs to:

```
Name:  lastname, first mi Address:  123 Main St.  City, State, Zip:  more...
Fieldx:  data1 Fieldy:  more data...
```

What I dont' want is the regular table data look with column headers across the top:

```
name                 Address
lastname, first mi   Some address...
```

I'm not sure what to look up to do this.  When i looked up tableless CSS, I only find forms and layouts.

Am I wrong here to thing I should be using the form layouts with CSS (and no tables)...it's just not a "form"?

edit:  do I just put everything inside a div and then in spans with float right?

Comment: I don't really see how your design is "column-based". What you have written in the first code block is just a bunch of inline text, which will be default and needs no styling at all.

Comment: use `ul > li` based structure, you can display data the way you want. Look at this example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/112983/using-divs-to-display-table-like-data

Answer (score 0):

I think DIVs are the way to go. DIVs give you much better flexibility when combined with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

What you have is structurally a list of name/value pairs, which corresponds to a two-column table. It could also be marked up as a `dl` element, if we take the liberal modern interpretation that `dl` is not really a definition list but a description list, which in turn is effectively a list of name/value pairs. And it could also be marked up as a `ul` element where each `li` element contains two `span` elements (with classes), but then you lose the array-like idea in the structure. Finally, you could use some `div` or `p` container, containing `span` elements with alternating classes.

All of this has little to do with semantics (meaning). Rather, it is about structure. Instead of considering which of the approaches is more “correct”, consider which is most comfortable in styling (and possibly in processing, e.g. in client-side scripting). If you want tabular layout, using a table is natural. (Somewhat amusingly, if you *don’t* want such layout, then you probably should not use a table, because old versions of IE don’t let you style a `table` element in a non-tabular way.)

If you intend to have the data as inline text as in your example, then I would use

```
<div class=foo>
<span class=name>Name</span> <span class=value>lastname, first mi</span>
<span class=name>Address</span> <span class=value>123 Main St. </span>
  ...
</div>
```

This is a bit verbose markup, but it can be styled easily, since `div` and `span` have no default styling (except that `div` implies line breaks before and after), and you can conveniently use class selectors.