# HTML markup for multi-day calendar events

Tags: html, css, calendar

I'm familiar with the standard colspan-based approach for displaying (multiweek or month view) calendars in HTML with events that span multiple days. (Google Calendar does this, as one of many examples.)

I'm curious if anyone knows of a table-less approach to achieve the same thing. Maybe it's just not important, and this is a "good" use of the table element, but I think it might be more relevant in this era of responsive design.

Here's an example of a responsive, table-less calendar. (No multi-day events, though.) https://pittsburghkids.org/calendar In its small-viewport version, it's no longer a table, semantically. Similarly, as @ThinkingStiff mentions below, if you're switching from "month view" to "list view" on the client side, a table doesn't really fit semantically either.

Comment: I'm aware that the prevailing opinion (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42169/if-you-were-programming-a-calendar-in-html-would-you-use-table-tags-or-div-tags?rq=1) has been for tables, but I'm also aware that many long-held assumptions are overturned by the prevalence of small viewports.

Answer (score 14):

### Calendars != Tables

Calendars are *not* semantically tables. They feel like tables because that is how we always see them, but for the data to be *semantically* tabular, each row would have to contain a unique entity, and they don't. In calendars the ***day* is the entity**.

The confusion lies in the fact that we also group days into weeks. People naturally think a month is a collection of weeks, but it is not, it's a collection of days. A month has, on average, 4.3 weeks. A row in a table **can't contain *part* of an entity or *multiple* entities.**

### Row == Entity, Column == Property

Compare it to, say, a shopping cart online. The items in your cart are tabular. Each **row** represents one type of **item** in your cart. Each **column** is either a **property** of the item (name, stock number, price) or an aggregate (quantity, total amount) of a property. You never see two different item types in a single row (because it wouldn't make sense) and a cart can't contain 4.3 rows.

### A Solution

For this demo I used `<divs>`, one for each day set to `display: inline-block`, but you'll probably want to use an `<ol>`. Days flow well when changing between month/week/day views (not possible with tables). For multi-day events, Javascript can do the layout.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/XXm8y/

#### Output:

[image]

#### Script:

```js
var events = [{ from: 3, to: 9 }, { from: 4, to: 4 }, { from: 9, to: 11 },{ from: 4, to: 12 }];

for( var eventIndex = 0, event; event = events[eventIndex], eventIndex < events.length; eventIndex++ ) {
    for( var dayIndex = event.from; dayIndex <= event.to; dayIndex++ ) {
        var dayElement = document.getElementById( 'day' + dayIndex ),
            firstDay = document.getElementsByClassName( 'event' + eventIndex ),
            top;
        if( firstDay.length ) {
            top = firstDay[0].style.top;
        } else {
            var eventCount = dayElement.getElementsByClassName( 'event' ).length;
            top = ( eventCount * 20 ) + 'px';
        };
        var html = '<div '
            + 'class="event event' + eventIndex + '" '
            + 'style="top: ' + top + ';">' 
            + eventIndex
            + '</div>';
        dayElement.insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeEnd', html );
    };        
};
​
```

#### CSS:

```css
#calendar {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 400px;
    width: 504px;    
}
.day {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 80px;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 72px;   
}
.day:nth-child( even ) {
    background-color: pink;
}
.day:nth-child( odd ) {
    background-color: lightblue;
}
.event {
    background-color: lightgrey;
    height: 20px;   
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
```

​

#### HTML:

```html
<div id="calendar">
    <div id="day1" class="day"></div><div id="day2" class="day"></div><div id="day3" class="day"></div><div id="day4" class="day"></div><div id="day5" class="day"></div><div id="day6" class="day"></div><div id="day7" class="day"></div><div id="day8" class="day"></div><div id="day9" class="day"></div><div id="day10" class="day"></div><div id="day11" class="day"></div><div id="day12" class="day"></div><div id="day13" class="day"></div><div id="day14" class="day"></div><div id="day15" class="day"></div><div id="day16" class="day"></div><div id="day17" class="day"></div><div id="day18" class="day"></div><div id="day19" class="day"></div><div id="day20" class="day"></div><div id="day21" class="day"></div><div id="day22" class="day"></div><div id="day23" class="day"></div><div id="day24" class="day"></div><div id="day25" class="day"></div><div id="day26" class="day"></div><div id="day27" class="day"></div><div id="day28" class="day"></div><div id="day29" class="day"></div><div id="day30" class="day"></div><div id="day31" class="day"></div>
</div>​
```

Comment: I think the hard question about multi-day events is how they displace events in the adjacent days. Tables and colspan make that pretty simple.

Comment: I think the complexity of this solution goes a long way toward showing that, ugly as it is, using tables may be more elegant than a workaround. This is a lot of Javascript to accomplish (almost) what a table "just does". (I say almost, because this solution won't deal with events that aren't a fixed height.)

Comment: @MichaelHellein Yeah, the table-less approach *is* a little more difficult for multi-day events. Its advantage is layout. Switching from month-view to day or week-view is a simple matter of add a class to the days with a new width and height.

Comment: Yep, that's exactly why I'm asking this question.

Comment: @MichaelHellein I updated with my thoughts on calendars != tables.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13813/discussion-between-michael-hellein-and-thinkingstiff)