# CSS: keep multiple elements in same place

Tags: css

I am writing a calendar and am trying to keep the calendar numbers which are contained in divs in the same place.  However, when I add text for an event in a div, the text seems to be pushing the numbers upwards. From reading I gather this has to do with block elements pushing one another around vertically.  I have set position in both the number div and the event div to relative because if I shift it to absolute, then all of the elements get printed on top of one another.  And I've tried all sorts of other combinations of css tags to no avail.

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AzsrJ/) illustrating the problem and the code:

css

```
table.calendar {
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 520px;
}
div.day-number   { 
    background:#999; 
    z-index:2; 
    top:0px; 
    right:1px; 
    padding:4px; 
    color:#fff; 
    font-weight:bold; 
    width:18px; 
    text-align:center;
}
td.calendar-day, td.calendar-day-np { 
    width:70px; 
    padding:5px 25px 5px 5px; 
    border-bottom:1px solid #999; 
    border-right:1px solid #999; 
}
div.event {
    position:relative; 
    z-index:3; 
    top:15px;
    text-width: 70px;
}
```

html

```
<table class="calendar">
    <tr>
        <td>Mon</td>
        <td>Tue</td>
        <td>Wed</td>
        <td>Thur</td>
        <td>Fri</td>
</tr>
<tr>
         <td class="calendar-day"><div class="day-number">14</div><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p></div></td>
    <td class="calendar-day"><div class="day-number">15</div><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p></div></td>
<td class="calendar-day"><div class="day-number">16</div><div class="event">4:00PM<br>Go to gym</div><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p></td>
    <td class="calendar-day"></td>
    <td class="calendar-day"><div class="day-number">18</div><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p></div></td>
            </tr></table>
```

Can anyone suggest a fix for this problem.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a js fiddle of how I think it should be done,

http://jsfiddle.net/CarlG/FCq3U/

You will notice that I have not used a table structure.

`Table` is used for tabular data which I don't think quite falls into the calendar category, the reason for this is that using `table` will restrict how you can manipulate the look and feel of the calendar using css.

Instead I have used `div` tags.

Comment: Changing the tag for day from div to span did the trick.  For the time being have left as table as there would be a lot of code to rewrite and I am still shaky on css.  But with the day-number as a span instead of div it no longer gets pushed around.  Thx!

Comment: No worries, you should really try to learn css, it helps alot!

Comment: @user1904273 if changing `div` to `span` worked, simply set your `div` CSS to `display:inline` - that's the only major difference between the two by default. It'll save you some HTML re-writing!

Comment: @GriffLab, although I generally too err on the side of fewer tables, I think a calendar is a pretty valid usage of them. [Here's a SO post that talks about it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42169/if-you-were-programming-a-calendar-in-html-would-you-use-table-tags-or-div-tags)

Comment: I just realized that changing div to span did not fix it.  What happened was I changed the css tag to span and in html changed the opening tag to span but left the closing tag as div.  This fixed problem but is obviously an error.  When I changed closing tag to </span> still have same problem.  Am trying to figure out what browser was thinking when it interpreted <span>16</div>

Answer (score 0):

add follwoing line in calendar-day class.

```
vertical-align:top;
```

Comment: you are use table , td are default to middle align.